# Health check is getting failed in https but not in http

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, kubernetes-health-check, google-cdn

Previously i set up load balancer and health check for http protocol and it got set up with no erro. Actually i was setting up load balancer for google cloud cdn. After this google cdn was not working so someone said it must be https so i edited load balancer and converted it to https load balancer.
After converting to https , i am facing failed health check. My health check is also in https.

Comment: 1) You will want both an HTTP and HTTPS front-ends. 2) Typically your backend is HTTP so your health check will also be HTTP. 3) Include details on your load balancer configuration - front-end, backend, and health check.

Comment: @John Hanley Thanks, health check is passed:)

Comment: Now how do i know https front-end is working? because ip of https front-end on browser showing "the page isn't working" basically no response. Though http front-end is working.

Answer (score 0):

You could curl your HTTP(S) load balancer IP and check the [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) to understand the actual issue.

curl -I [load balancer IP]

I would like to mention here that HTTP(S) load balancer is a Proxy and requests from clients are terminated at the load balancing layer, then proxied over to your backends. Please find HTTP(S) Load Balancing Concepts [documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/).

Just to clarify here that you can enable Google Cloud CDN for an existing HTTP(S) load balancer backend service or backend bucket or enable it while creating a new one. So, it will work with both HTTP and HTTPS load balancer. Here is the [public documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-cdn#enable) on that.

I would recommend posting this type of questions in ServerFault as StackOverflow is for Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers.